# Deleting blank lines ONLY if they are followed by a non-blank line... multiple blank lines in a row should be deleted

Tags: lines

I have a txt file that is basically in address form, like so:

```
John Smith
123 Address Way
Blah Blah Blah
```

Each block of text is followed by 3 blank lines (which I want). However, some of the addresses in the file are missing data, thus they are blank like so:

```
John Smith
123 Address Way

Blah Blah Blah
```

I want to keep the multiple (3) blank lines after each data, but I want to delete only the single blank lines.

Anybody have any ideas? All the stuff on google I've found relates to deleting multiple blank lines, or all blank lines... the opposite of what I need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very unclear. What language are you working in? What have you tried so far that isn't working? Is this a homework assignment? You need to edit your question and add more details if you expect to get an answer; there isn't near enough here to go on to help you.

Comment: Au contraire: this is only a tiny bit underspecified.  It would have been nice if the OP had said what language they would prefer to use, but it's hardly required for a good answer.

Comment: @Zack: While you can definitely guess, it's hardly conducive to teaching people to ask better questions, and without any additional information it's a bad question. I didn't downvote or vote to close; I gave the poster a suggestion that they should improve it. But if you want to spend your time answering questions in detail (as you have here) only to find out they mean something totally differently, or that they're doing a homework assignment in C or VBA where your answer doesn't work, it's your time. :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new didn't notice your comments! I would very much prefer to use something like sed or awk for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have one of these problems, and the file is not gigantic, one of the best tools for the job is perl in [`undef $/`](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perlvar.pod#INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) mode, which makes it read the entire file as one big string; this allows you to match `\n` just like any other character.

At the character level, assuming there is no trailing horizontal whitespace on any line, a blank line is *two* newline characters in a row; two blank lines is three newline characters, and so on.  To delete a blank line, you delete one of the two newline characters. Now, if you just write `s/\n\n/\n/g`, that will do more than you want, because `\n\n` will match pairs of newlines *within* longer runs of newlines.  So you need a construct that will match two newlines in a row but *only if* they are not preceded or followed by more newlines.  This is what [look-around assertions](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perlre.pod#Look-Around_Assertions) are for.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/ } s/\s+$//mg; s/(?<!\n)\n\n(?!\n)/\n/sg'
```

should do the job.  It will have the side effect of deleting trailing whitespace, if any, from every line of the file.  If you want to delete double blank lines as well as single blank lines (but still not *triple* blank lines), you just have to adjust the middle of the second RE:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/ } s/\s+$//mg; s/(?<!\n)\n{2,3}(?!\n)/\n/sg'
```

Comment: thanks! However, it's not working...  it deletes all of the blank lines, not just the single ones.

Comment: Are you sure you typed it in *exactly* as shown? What version of Perl do you have? What OS? And it would help if you posted a larger excerpt of your input file, so we can see the record boundaries for ourselves.